# How do you fight against grapplers?

Tags: ultra-street-fighter-iv

I've just picked up Ultra Street Fighter 4, and I'm still just trying to learn the basic footsies before I even delve into good punishes and combos. In playing Arcade mode, I've found that grappling characters like Abel and Hugo are much more difficult for me to handle than other characters.

If I'm using a character with sub-par or non-existent ranged attacks and keep-away isn't really an option, how should I fight against these characters? If they block a single attack it seems like I'm immediately caught in a command throw, which I haven't been able to counter (is it even possible?).

What strategies should be used against command-throw-happy opponents as characters with limited or no ranged options?

Answer (score 4):

A good starting strategy is to learn to bait the command throws and neutral jump.
Use a fast poke or a poke with some blockstun against command throw characters. If you connect, then follow it up with a combo. If you don't connect and instead are blocked then you should be safer.

I play Zangief frequently and that's generally what gets me. A good command throw player won't use that many command throws. It is the threat of the command throw that allows the player to force positioning. If I whiff on a command throw I will get punished hard.